# Не работает сборка gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

```
Выдает ошибку:
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" run dev --scripts-prepend- 
node-path=auto

> tour@1.0.0 dev C:\frontend\verstka\granit
> gulp watch --dev --sync

[20:45:33] Using gulpfile C:\frontend\verstka\granit\gulpfile.js
[20:45:33] Starting 'watch'...
[20:45:33] Starting 'clear'...
[20:45:33] Finished 'clear' after 42 ms
[20:45:33] Starting 'styles'...
[20:45:33] Starting 'img'...
[20:45:33] Starting 'html'...
[20:45:33] Starting 'js'...
[20:45:33] Starting 'fonts'...
[20:45:33] 'js' errored after 234 ms
[20:45:33] GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected line terminator
File: C:\frontend\verstka\granit\src\js\main.min.js
Line: 1
[20:45:33] 'watch' errored after 297 ms
[20:45:33] The following tasks did not complete: styles, img, html, fonts
[20:45:33] Did you forget to signal async completion?
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tour@1.0.0 dev: `gulp watch --dev --sync`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tour@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
 logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10- 
 02T17_45_33_624Z-debug.log

 Process finished with exit code 1

const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const del = require('del');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify  = require('gulp-uglify');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');
const gcmq = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries');
const less = require('gulp-less');
const smartgrid = require('smart-grid');

const isDev = (process.argv.indexOf('--dev') !== -1);
const isProd = !isDev;
const isSync = (process.argv.indexOf('--sync') !== -1);


function clear(){
  return del('build/*');
}

function styles(){
  return gulp.src('./src/css/+(styles|styles-per|styles-ie9).less')
           .pipe(gulpif(isDev, sourcemaps.init()))
           .pipe(less())
           //.pipe(concat('style.css'))
           .pipe(gcmq())
           .pipe(autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['> 0.1%'],
                cascade: false
            }))
           //.on('error', console.error.bind(console))
           .pipe(gulpif(isProd, cleanCSS({
                level: 2
           })))
           .pipe(gulpif(isDev, sourcemaps.write()))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'))
           .pipe(gulpif(isSync, browserSync.stream()));
}

function img(){
  return gulp.src('./src/img/**/*')
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img'))
}
  function fonts(){
  return gulp.src('./src/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts'))
}

  function js(){
  return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify()) // Минифицирует js
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function html(){
 return gulp.src('./src/*.html')
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
           .pipe(gulpif(isSync, browserSync.stream()));
}

function watch(){
if(isSync){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build/",
        }
    });
}
gulp.watch('./src/fonts/**/*.js', fonts);
gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', js);
gulp.watch('./src/css/**/*.less', styles);
gulp.watch('./src/**/*.html', html);
gulp.watch('./smartgrid.js', grid);
}

function grid(done){
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./smartgrid.js')];

let settings = require('./smartgrid.js');
smartgrid('./src/css', settings);

settings.offset = '3.1%';
settings.filename = 'smart-grid-per';
smartgrid('./src/css', settings);

done();
}

  let build = gulp.series(clear, 
    gulp.parallel(styles, img, html,js,fonts)
  );

gulp.task('build', gulp.series(grid, build));
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(build, watch));
gulp.task('grid', grid);
{
 "name": "granit",
 "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "gulp watch --dev --sync",
  "build": "gulp build"
  },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
  "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
  "del": "^5.1.0",
  "gulp": "^4.0.2",
  "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.0",
  "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
  "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
  "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
  "gulp-less": "^4.0.1",
   "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
   "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
  "smart-grid": "^2.1.2"
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function watch(){
if(isSync){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build/",
        }
    });
}
gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', js);
gulp.watch('./src/fonts/**/*', fonts);
gulp.watch('./src/css/**/*.less', styles);
gulp.watch('./src/**/*.html', html);
gulp.watch('./smartgrid.js', grid);
}
function js(){
   return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['@babel/env']
    }))
    .pipe(uglify()) // Минифицирует js
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
   }
```